# Disable merge button on GitHub till a pull request is approved

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I want to achieve merge button diable functionality similar to `STASH` in `GitHub` where the button is disabled till a pull request is approved. By default, `GitHub`  pull requests are always able to merge i.e. merge button is enabled, disregard of approval from peers.

Any suggestions how can I achieve this goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub does not natively support this functionality as it is right now.

That said, there's [evidence](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2016/02/16/github-responds-to-letter-regarding-developers-concerns-says-surprises-are-coming/) that supports that they are now open to [new ideas](https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github#dear-open-source-maintainers) to improve the software.

GitHub only contains the basic necessities for code-reviewing, and that is commenting.

Answer (score 2):

You can tray options for protect branches.

https://help.github.com/articles/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/

Answer (score 0):

I came across a tool named [Zappr](https://github.com/zalando/zappr) that does the same. However at this point of time this project is not available for GitHub Enterprise but only for open source projects on GitHub.